# Authorize.Net SIM Method With Response using C#

Tags: c#, authorize.net

I have been trying to implement the Authorize.NEt SIM Method using the information given on their website and tutorials.But i have been only able to redirect to their payment gateway using the ddl provided by them.I need a way to get a response from SIM Method to know about the transaction status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use [relay response](http://developer.authorize.net/guides/SIM/Receipt_Options/Relay_Response.htm) or [silent post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/) (I am the author of that blog post).

Comment: tnks for ur response.But can u tell me how to read that response from the silent post using c#......

Comment: It's no different then handling any POST data like that from a form.

Comment: my project is not hosted on public IP so can u tell me if i'll be able to work with silent post url??And is it necessary for the silent post url to be on public IP???

Comment: It's ok to be on a non-public IP for silent post as long as you allow http submissions from authorize.net through to reach your silent post script. If you cannot do this then you cannot use silent post or relay response.